# Tensorflow: ValueError Occured when fetching parameters out in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to look into the matrix multiplication in **LSTM cells**, the model I'm using is Baidu's DeepSpeech1 implemented in Tensorflow. However, when I tried to fetch the matrix(weights and [inputs, h]) that perform multiplication operation in the LSTM cells, I created an interactivesession named sess, and both used **"print(Tensor.eval())"** and **"print(sess.run(args))"** where the BasicLSTMCell stated in Tensorflow(rnn_cell_impl.py). But, I got the same ValueError as below. How can I fetch the values out?

```
concat = _quantized_linear([inputs, h], 4 * self._num_units, True,
                           quantization=self._quantization, fake_quant_weights=self._fake_quant_weights)

matrix = array_ops.concat([inputs, h], 1)
print(matrix.eval())
# i = input_gate, j = new_input, f = forget_gate, o = output_gate
i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(value=concat, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)

new_c = (
    c * sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * self._activation(j))
new_h = self._activation(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.
[The ValueError Raised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtbMi.png)

Comment: Can u post ur error?

Comment: I have posted the error under the question. I have tried several methods, but got the same ValueError "operation has been marked as not fetchable" ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly fetch the values of tensors created inside a tensorflow conditional or while loop.

Your options are to use static_rnn (which doesn't create a loop) or to call the same lstmcell outside of a loop to get tensors for its state which are fetchable.

Comment: You mean call a same lstmcell and feed in the same value as the orignal cell?

Comment: And does the basiclstmcell structure cause this error or the bidirectional_dynamic_rnn structure?

Comment: Yes call the same cell but outside of the bidirectional rnn structure